# Road Bike overhaul

Tags: repair, mechanical, road

Can someone recommend a complete step by step book or other media that can help me with this project I am about to take on. Please include the list of tools too.
I have an old Jamis road bike I would like to completely strip down and build up. 
Thank you for helping!

Comment: Mainly, you repack the bearings and clean/lube the chain.  And do whatever service seems necessary on the brakes (possibly replacing the cables and pads).  If it's "old" then the bearings are loose balls or balls in "cages" (vs cartridge bearings).

Comment: Why do you want to completely strip it down? Replace the obvious things like brake pads and what not, and if other things are not good, replace them as needed.

Comment: [Richard's Bicycle Book](https://www.amazon.com/Richards-Bicycle-Book-Richard-Ballantine/dp/034529453X) is an oldy but a goody.

Comment: Check out Sheldon Brown and Park Tools - both have lots of information and Park Tools also has videos for many procedures.  As for tools - look for a reasonable priced all-in-one toolkit to get you started (don't get the cheapest ones IMHO) and supplement with a torque wrench and possibly some star-drive tool bits.  Get some grease (I use white lithium, its cheap and long lasting) and some chain lube (search this forum for lots and lots on THAT topic!). A work stand will be brilliant for a complete strip down, but not 100% necessary.  Add to the kit as you go along (subject to money!)